# Adding a group of controls to a list

Tags: c#, iteration

I am trying to add the values of 3 TextBox controls to a List, the problem is that these controls are added programmatically by the click of a button. I can't figure out how to get 3 TextBoxes grouped together so I can add their values to the List.

Here's some code:

Button click to add controls:

```
protected void Button_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (ViewState["count"] != null)
    {
        count = (int)ViewState["count"];
    }
    count = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count + 1;
    ViewState["count"] = count;
    createcontrols();
}
```

Method to add the controls

```
protected void createcontrols()
{
    int count = 0;
    if (ViewState["count"] != null)
    {
        count = (int)ViewState["count"];
    }
    while (PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count < count)
    {
        TextBox TextBox_Name = new TextBox();
        TextBox TextBox_MemberNo = new TextBox();
        TextBox TextBox_Points = new TextBox();
        TextBox_Name.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Navn");
        TextBox_Name.ID = "TextBox_Name" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_Name.CssClass = "input-small";
        TextBox_MemberNo.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Medlemsnr.");
        TextBox_MemberNo.ID = "TextBox_MemberNo" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_MemberNo.CssClass = "input-small";
        TextBox_Points.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Point");
        TextBox_Points.ID = "TextBox_Points" + PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Count.ToString();
        TextBox_Points.CssClass = "input-small";
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_Name);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_MemberNo);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(TextBox_Points);
        PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
```

Finally the code that runs on the save button click, to add the items to the list:

```
public struct content
{
    public string name;
    public string memberNo;
    public int points;
}

List<content> rows = new List<content>();

protected void LinkButton_Submit_Attendees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox)
        {
            string txt = item.ID.ToString(); // String to run RegEx on
            string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
            string re2 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1

            Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            Match m = r.Match(txt);

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].ToString());
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)item;

            content row = new content();
            if(item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("Name"))
            {
                row.name = txtBox.Text;
            }
            else if (item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("MemberNo"))
            {
                row.memberNo = txtBox.Text;
            }
            else if (item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("Points"))
            {
                row.points = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is that for every third control this iterates over, the `rows.Add(row)` is called with `row.name, row.memberNo and row.points` all with their respective values.

Comment: I'd use a TableLayoutPanel to do that ... if I understand your underlying requirement.

Comment: Add an `int` counter, starting at 1, and check for `if (counter % 3 == 0)` to see if it's divisible by three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use Linq's `OfType` find all your `TextBoxes` in the `PlaceHolder`:

   ```
   var alltxt = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
   ```

You can use Linq for all:

```
List<content> rows = PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Select(txt => new{
        Txt = txt,
        Number = new String(txt.ID.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
     })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
    .Select(g => new content{ 
        name = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Name")).Txt.Text,
        memberNo = g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_MemberNo")).Txt.Text,
        points = int.Parse(g.First(x => x.Txt.ID.StartsWith("TextBox_Points")).Txt.Text)
    })
    .ToList();
```

I'm grouping by the numeric suffix that you have used for the ID (1-n).

Comment: This looks like a really smart solution, although I have no experience with Linq. I do have some questions to your solution though: 
On this line `Number = new String(txt.Id.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)))`
Visual Web Developer 2010 Express throws this exception: 
` 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
If I change `Id` to `ID` it tells me that the overloaded method has inv. args

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters on the comment.

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: Yes of course, the property in webcontrols is `ID` not `Id` and the `string` constructor takes a `Char[]` instead of a `IEnumerable<Char>`, so call `ToArray()` at the end. Edited my answer. :)

Comment: Updated my answer, note that i've also changed `...Text` to `....Txt.Text` since `group.First` returns an instance of the anonymous type which contains a property `Txt` that references the `TextBox`.

Comment: Oh wow, I went with your answer because you just opened my eyes to Linq, I really have to look into Linq! Looks like a real timesaver, both performance wise and coding wise.

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: Although i love Linq it's not necessarily the most efficient approach. But you should look for the most readable approach at the first time anyway. In this method it doesn't  matter if it takes a millisecond more or less.

Comment: @TimeSchmelter Sure, ofcourse.
I was wondering if you possible had the time, could you comment your code in a way that explains it a bit more thoroughly? If I've understood it right `x` and `g` are variables you're defining for the first time in the GroupBy and Select statements, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your LinkButton_Submit_Attendees_Click function:

```
protected void LinkButton_Submit_Attendees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        content row = new content();
foreach (Control item in PlaceHolder_ForEntries.Controls)
{
    if (item is TextBox)
    {
        string txt = item.ID.ToString(); // String to run RegEx on
        string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
        string re2 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1

        Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(txt);

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].ToString());
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)item;

        if(item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("Name"))
        {
            row.name = txtBox.Text;
        }
        else if (item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("MemberNo"))
        {
            row.memberNo = txtBox.Text;
        }
        else if (item.ID.Contains(id.ToString()) && item.ID.Contains("Points"))
        {
            row.points = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text);
        }
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.name)
  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.memberNo)
  && row.points > 0)){
        rows.Add(row);
        row = new content();
}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That worked partially!
The only problem left is that `row.points` is an `int` so that validates true every time. I tried `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.points.ToString))` and `row.points.ToString() != ""` which still validates true, it just adds a '0' to `row.points`. While this **can** be '0', it is not the value I had provided the TextBox. Any solutions for this problem?